# How to skip user input after timeout in python

Tags: python-3.x, user-input

I want to be able to receive user input like this:

```
while True:
    curr_time = time.time()
    timeout = curr_time+30 // after 30 seconds the bottom input code should be skipped
    message = input("Your message: ")
    //the rest of the code
```

And after 30 seconds or so then the code should just continue executing the rest of the code and then start over in the while loop, where there will be another 30 second wait before the input option will just be skipped and the loop continues...

Answer (score -3):

Here is a code snippet it may help?

```
# get the character of a key pressed (no return key needed)
# works only in the command window and with Windows OS
from msvcrt import getch
print "press a char key (escape key to exit)"
while True:
    z = …

Well you could just use a Thread object to do the counting for you and then in your main program everytime the user enters a key, you just call a function of the Thread object counting that returns it's current value.

The example below might help.

# counterTest.py, …
```